# How to disable a graphql filter if the variable is not set?

Tags: variables, graphql, hasura

I am working on [a page with configurable filters](https://my.metagame.wtf). The graphql query looks like:

```
query GetPlayers(
  $offset: Int
  $limit: Int
  $skillIds: [uuid!] = null
  $playerTypeIds: [Int!] = null
  $availability: Int = null
  $timezones: [String!] = null
  $search: String = null
) {
  player(
    order_by: { total_xp: desc }
    offset: $offset
    limit: $limit
    where: {
      availability_hours: { _gte: $availability }
      timezone: { _in: $timezones }
      player_type_id: { _in: $playerTypeIds }
      Player_Skills: { Skill: { id: { _in: $skillIds } } }
      _or: [
        { username: { _ilike: $search } }
        { ethereum_address: { _ilike: $search } }
      ]
    }
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

I would like the default behavior to be to return all entries. I am using Hasura 1.3.3 and `null` is interpreted as `{}` which will return all entries. The only problem is the `Player_Skills: { Skill: { id: { _in: $skillIds } } }` line. There is a join table with foreign keys referring to the `players` and `skills` tables, and that line will only return players who have at least one entry in that table.

Is it possible to form a query that will ignore the skills filter if `$skillIds` is `null`?

Comment: just prepare and pass $where object instead of subprops